# Adding a One-to-Many Relationship on a Model with Compound ID in Prisma

Tags: reactjs, node.js, prisma

Forgive my ignorance on creating schema. I am attempting to add a one to many relationship to a model with a compound ID. Here is that model:

```
model UserPlantSpeciesInventoried {
  userId String
  user   User   @relation("user", fields: [userId], references: [id])

  plantSpeciesId String
  plantSpecies   PlantSpecies @relation("plantSpecies", fields: [plantSpeciesId], references: [id])

  inventoryReadyByDate InventoryReadyByDate[]

  @@id([userId, plantSpeciesId])
}
```

This model has it's ID autogenerated. It is a unique link between a user and a "Plant Species", indicating it is in the user's inventory.

The user will have some inventory ready at different times. For example, they may have 3 plants ready in July, and 2 in August. This in my opinion would be handled well by another model here:

```
model InventoryReadyByDate {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  userPlantSpeciesInventoried   UserPlantSpeciesInventoried @relation(fields: [userPlantSpeciesInventoriedId], references: [userId_plantSpeciesId])
  userPlantSpeciesInventoriedId String

  quantity Int @default(0)

  dateReadyBy DateTime
}
```

However Prisma throws this error

> Error validating: The argument `references` must refer only to
> existing fields in the related model `UserPlantSpeciesInventoried`.
> The following fields do not exist in the related model:
> userId_plantSpeciesId

creating a custom ID name does not resolve this error. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might just be in your syntax for [Multi-field relations in relational databases](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations/one-to-many-relations#multi-field-relations-in-relational-databases)
 which should not be:

```
  userPlantSpeciesInventoried   UserPlantSpeciesInventoried @relation(fields: [userPlantSpeciesInventoriedId], references: [userId_plantSpeciesId])
```

but instead:

```
  userPlantSpeciesInventoried   UserPlantSpeciesInventoried @relation(fields: [userPlantSpeciesInventoriedId], references: [userId, plantSpeciesId])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
model InventoryReadyByDate {
  id                          String                      @id @default(cuid())
  userPlantSpeciesInventoried UserPlantSpeciesInventoried @relation(fields: [userId, plantSpeciesId], references: [userId, plantSpeciesId])
  userId                      String
  plantSpeciesId              String

  quantity Int @default(0)

  dateReadyBy DateTime
}
```

Thank you @Nelloverflow for helping me figure this out. I needed to pass both ids that make up the compound Id.